# how do I write to a file and not removing the content of the text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

how do I write to a file and not removing the file/the content of the file

```
values = '113'
with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
    for row in values:
        output.write(str(row) + '\n')
```

how do I fix it?

and I planing to use it as a score board of my snake game I made in pygame

Comment: basically you want to append to a file. This behaviour can be achieved by using the mode `a` insteaf of `w`. This beeing said: This question has already been answered e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 'append' attribute ('a') in the open function:

```
values = '113'
with open("file.txt", 'a') as output:
    for row in values:
        output.write(str(row) + '\n')
```

Comment: yes I worked thanks

Comment: one question more I can't have a int to write

Comment: You are writing a text file, so you need to write str values, not int or float. Convert your int to str using `str(int_val)`.

Comment: @zaze please mark it as an answer. otherwise people will continue to comment